# SVN my project not showing up

Tags: java, eclipse, svn

I was trying to use SVN today as i was doing all my changes in my webproject on the same folder/files, so wanted to try SVN for version control. However when i installed it and tried to create a repository named "project"...however my servlets/JS files/JSP files folder(package) is also named as Project...

Suddenly after i create the SVN repository i don't see all the work i did..all my .class file and everything else is wiped out. I went to Eclipse workspace i see nothing but .svn...Can someone please help me how to retrieve my work? It is many hours worth of work.

Thanks for your help!
[image]

Comment: would be good if you can rewrite this as sequence of steps with the locations where the project files were present where the repository was created and what actions you performed on each of these.

Comment: the question is very unclear..cannot understand...

Comment: please rephrase the question. The key is to write smaller sentences.

Comment: Did you commit on the first place?

Comment: Sorry...honestly i was experimenting and dint know what i was doing.

Comment: I went into SVN Repositories->right clicked->New Repository (Named it as "Project"). Then i selected the Location as C:/ and created a new folder ("Eclipse Repo"). Thats it suddenly my folder named "Project" in the project explorer...disappeared.. and i see following now in the Project Explorer....(>Eclipse Repo 1(file:///c:/Eclipse Repo:Eclipse Repo. When i expand this folder i see "Project 1" folder(nothing in the folder).

Comment: Then i also see one more folder in the Project Explorer...(>Project1 1 [file:///C:/Eclipse Repo:Project]. just this folder and nothing else under it.

Comment: And in the SVN Repositories-> I see following-> file:///C:/Eclipse Repo under this ->Project 1 and ROOT1 and under ROTT1->Project 1 and Revisions.

Comment: Apart from above steps I have not committed or done anything.....

Answer (score 1):

First You can commit your projects by using [tortoise svn](http://www.shokhirev.com/nikolai/programs/SVN/svn.html) after creating one repository in SVN.
Second you can checkout your project with eclipse.See [this article](http://www.dennisplucinik.com/blog/2011/02/27/how-to-connect-with-eclipse-to-a-subversion-repository-hosted-on-a-mediatemple-dv-server/) to connect SVN with eclipse.